# Which are best repo for Cent OS 5.7?

Tags: centos, package-management, repository

Which are best repo for Cent OS 5.7?
Should I install apt-get and use other deb packages on Cent OS?

I mainly used Ubuntu which is really easy to update any packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use deb packages in CentOS, even if install apt-get, things are too much different between the distributions.

Take a look at [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and [RPMForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge), also at the [CentOS Wiki entry on repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

Answer (score 1):

I remember a recent question about installing apt in Fedora. Fedora, RHEL, and CentOS are RPM-based Linux distros. In fact, they're all derived from Red Hat technologies. You're going to have learn to use yum.

As for good repositories, you could look at Renan's suggestions. There's also RPM Fusion which is a fan favorite. http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/